# In 1 Corinthians 8:6, should δι αὐτοῦ ἡμεῖς be translated "because of whom we exist" or "through whom we exist"?

Tags: translation-philosophy, 1-corinthians, creation, biblical-theology

1 Corinthians 8:6 ESV translation:

> yet for us there is one God, the Father, from whom are all things and
> for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, **through** whom are all
> things and **through** whom we exist.

1 Corinthians 8:6 translation proposal:

> yet for us there is only one God, the Father, from whom are all things
> and for whom we exist, and one Lord, Jesus Christ, **because of** whom
> are all things and **because of** whom we exist.

In numerous other passages within the New Testament, the term "dia" or "di" has been rendered "because of" or "on account of" even in the primary translations. The context here would clarify that all things were created from God because of Jesus, and we exist for God and because of Jesus.

Why this clarification is extremely important is because by translating "di" as "through", it fogs the text and makes it appear that the world was created "through" Jesus, as if to say that Jesus was the architect or even the Creator himself, which would promote the doctrine of the Trinity and Jesus as a co-creator alongside the Father God.

Rendering the passage "because of" makes sense because it reveals that everything was created *from* the Father God *because of* his Son Jesus, and we exist *for* God and *because of* Jesus.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I recommend Daniel B Wallace's _Beyond the Basics_ where there is a comprehensive treatment of Greek prepositions and their various contextual meanings. P355 and following. The prepositions do not mean what we want them to mean, they mean what they mean. This is a theological question and I am voting to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Let me begin by quoting a very literal version, the BLB for 1 Cor 8:6:

> yet to us there is one God the Father, of whom are all things, and we
> for Him; and one Lord, Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we
> through Him.

Note that words like "live" and "exist" do not exist in the original Greek - such are interpretations of some versions to make the English more sensible.  So, what does this verse mean?  Let me set this out in the typical Hebrew parallelism that undergirds this verse:

> to us:
>
> - one God, the Father, **of** whom all things, and we **for** Him
> - and one Lord, Jesus Christ, **by** whom all things, and we for **by** Him

Thus, we have three pertinent prepositions whose meaning all overlap, namely:

- ἐξ (ex) = from out, of, out from among, from, suggesting from the interior outwards.
- εἰς (eis) = into, in, unto, to, upon, towards, for, among
- διά (dia) = through, throughout, by the instrumentality of (with the genitive as here in both the last two prepositions)

Let me quote Ellicott who appears to anticipate the OP's question by more than 200 years:

> (6) **But to us**.—Though this be so, yet for us Christians there
> exists but one God the Father, from whom alone every created thing has
> come, and for (not “in”) whom alone we exist; and one Lord Jesus
> Christ, through whom all things are created (John 1:3), and we
> Christians created spiritually by Him. All creation is of the Father
> through the Son. All creation is for the Father and likewise for the
> Son. (See Colossians 1:16.) The words “we by Him” must not be regarded
> as a repetition of part of the thought of the previous sentence; but
> as the words “by whom are all things” express the fact of physical
> creation, so the words, “we by Him,” attribute our spiritual
> re-creation as Christians to the same source. (See Galatians 6:15;
> Ephesians 2:10.) This sixth verse then sweeps away completely any
> pantheistic conception which might have been thought to be in the
> previous words. Even granting, for argument sake, that such gods or
> lords do exist, we have but one God, one Lord.

Let me sound a warning here that it is dangerous to go beyond Scripture and make distinctions that the Scripture does not make.  Paul's point here appears to be at least two things:

1. The extremely close relationship between the Father and Son
2. The close working of both in creation and sustaining of all things.

Comment: @Joshua B. I totally agree with Dottard here. There is a difference between the word "by" and the word, "through." One of the definitions of by is "Origin." It means "by the agency of." The word "through also has various applications and one of them is: "The manner in which something is achieved." It is easy to distinguish the difference between these two prepositions by keeping in mind that "by" is mostly used when referring to a means of something, and "through" is used in relation to a process. This is clearly seen at John 1:3, Colossians 1:16, Hebrews 1:10 and Revelation 3:14.